# Run Kubernetes api server in minikube in verbose mode

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Is it possible to run the kubernetes api-server in minikube with maximum log verbosity?

```
$ minikube start --v 4
```

didn't work for me. When I exec into the api-server container and do ps, the api-server commandline didn't have --v=4 in it. So, minikube is not passing the --v = 4 down to the api-server.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4201

Answer (score 2):

there is an error in the parameters, try this instead

```
minikube start --v=7
```

Comment: please take a look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/docs/configuring_kubernetes.md#kubeadm) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4201)  `minikube start --extra-config=apiserver.v=10`